# In game relativity concept

Tags: view, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am trying to develop a game and can't figure out the best solution to it. 
So my idea is when a user tries to leave an area as the picture describes below, i want the user to think they are leaving but their view just basically does a 180 without them realizing it. For example: http://mathszone.webspace.virginmedia.com/images/thumb-149.jpg

If this picture from the above link was the perimeter of my map, once the user walks over the perimeter line, I want their view to basically do a 180 and they are walking right back towards the center of the map. How would I go about doing this. Since they can still see beyond the perimeter, do i just reflect what is behind them and once they reach the perimeter line, their character rotates 180 degrees?

Comment: Well if you reflect then the user will recognise pretty quickly of being inside box.  Is your aim to get around the problem with floating point precision problems and large worlds?

Comment: What do you mean "view does a 180"  - is there a scene change? Can the player still see the other side?

Comment: I am trying to understand the best solution to this problem through concept first and then programmability

Comment: I want the user to not realize there is a screen change. So for example, if a user is walking through a forest away from their house, i want it so when they reach the boundary, they will be walking back towards their house

Comment: _"i want it so when they reach the boundary, they will be walking back towards their house"_ - why do you want to do that?

Comment: It is for a horror game and I want it so if the person tries to leave the house's boundaries in the forest, they will be redirected right back towards the house. So every time they think they are leaving, they are actually heading right back

Answer (score 0):

If the user is walking and seeing a forest and suddenly faces a house that he left behind there, it will be impossible to hide the change of direction.
Maybe you can think in others workarounds like:

- Use a high density fog.
- Use a dark scenario.
- Use a really big scenario where the limits are practically a pattern (so, when the player is close of limits, the view of the landscape is almost the same in 360º)

On the other hand you can use http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Reflect.html to change the user direction and get the desired effect.

Maybe this tutorial can help:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_p5H0wEN8Y